# Laravel 4.2 application encoding from UTF8 to iso-8859-1

Tags: html, sql-server, laravel, encoding

The database is based on MSSql and Laravel is successfully talking to it. Database is base on latin2 encoding so my Laravel app has to be iso-8859-1 istead UTF-8. Seems like entire laravel is shouting UTF8 though. I can't find anything in config files.

I have changed database encoding in connection string to be lating1 but that still doesn't' change anything.

When an entry is made form VB desktop application (my colleague is working on that) and he saves a £ symbol to the db, it goes there fine, although when I try to read that it gives me � symbol.

On the other hand if from Form::open tag I create an entry in the database the £ gets prefixed with something weird!

Also I have added `<meta charset="iso-8859-1">` to the html tag of the website but when i go in firefox to see page info still tells me that the website is in UTF8. I tried changing some of the files to the western encoding (Sublime save as ->with formating) like index.php, routes.php but the website still shows as UTF8...

Any help/ advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the **charset** and **collation** for you database connection (in `app/config/database.php`), to `'collation' => 'latin2'` and `'charset' => 'latin2_general_ci'`?

Comment: I just did - unfortunately no difference... Thank you for the idea though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I have done the following:

- Changed the form helper /project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/llluminate/Html/FormBuilder.php in line 106

this:

```
$attributes['accept-charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

to:

```
    $attributes['accept-charset'] = 'latin1';
```

This way all of the forms were imputing to the database right symbols.
After this as my app is not big I have created helper to convert a given string from lating1 to UTF8 like this:

```
public static function convertToUtf8($string){
    return $converted = iconv ('latin1' , 'utf-8' , $string);
}
```

And it's all working fine :)